# Who is the First referring to?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, hellblazer

In the hellblazer story ["Confessional"](http://hellblazer.wikia.com/wiki/Hellblazer_Special_1) set in the 1960s, a demon named the First is talking to someone and, while looking at a crucifix mentions:

> D'you know he's coming back? Oh yes.  He'll be born in South Central Los Angeles this time.
>
> He'll run away with the eight-tray gangsters until he realizes who he is.  After that he'll work tirelessly for the peaceful advancement of African-American culture..
>
> He'll end up leading a green anarchist coalition in Hell's Kitchen, and a man named Geldoff will kiss him on the cheek before an NYPD swat team.

Later before changing the topic, he also drops:

> All the same... he'll look pretty good up there with dreadlocks and a fender stratocaster, won't he?

Who is he talking about?

This is *way* too specific for the writer (Garth Ennis) to just be making up.  The story itself was published in 1993, giving Ennis plenty of history for the demon to give as prophesy.

I've been wracking google and wikipedia looking for someone who fits the bill, but with no luck.  Particularly, it seems we're looking for someone

- Born in LA in the 1960s or early 1970s
- [Spent time in gangs](http://www.streetgangs.com/crips/83gc#sthash.adHvSH6u.dpbs)
- Promoted African-American culture, possibly civil rights
- Moved to New York
- Promoted [Green Anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_anarchism)
- Had Dreadlocks
- Played Guitar or Bass, possibly professionally
- Possibly met or knew [Bob Geldof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Geldof)

Additionally, one might also assume

- African-American male
- The move to New York was in the late 70s or 80s
- Died before 1993

I've found some [individuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzz_Skillings) and [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOVE) that seem to come close, but not hit the mark.  Anyone know who this is?

Comment: Where do you get the assumption that he died before 1993?

Comment: In some the text I elided, the demon alludes to the person dying.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I haven't read the Hellblazer graphic novels, so this is just a guess based on general knowledge. If there's a canonical in-universe or (pardon the expression) ["word of god"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) explanation I'll happily bow out.

I don't think the demon is talking about a "real", i.e. objectively-verifiable person. The demon is giving a "prophecy" (can demons be prophetic?) of the post-1993 (publication date of the story) return of the Biblical Jesus Christ. All the details that are mentioned can apply anywhere between the late 1960's and today, May 2015. [South Central L.A.](http://www.southcentralhistory.com/) is still a disadvantaged neighborhood, the [8-Trey (Tray) Gangsters (AKA The Crips)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crips) are still very much in business, the [Green Anarchists](http://www.anarchy.no/green.html) are still around, [Bob Geldoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Geldof) is still alive and politically active, and [Hell's Kitchen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Kitchen,_Manhattan) is still Hell's Kitchen, albeit a bit more [gentrified](https://www.airbnb.com/locations/new-york/hell-s-kitchen) these days.
Why post-1993? If the [Second Coming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming) had happened before now I think we would have heard about it.

Comment: I think it's a joke about a person, too - there would be no point in it, if it wasn't about someone known.

Comment: @Mithoron - I think "point" would just be that the version of Jesus being described--a black former gang member who turned to far left activism and rockin' out on a guitar--would defy all the expectations of the conservative white fundamentalists who played such a prominent role in the "culture wars" of the 1990s. The use of a name similar, but not identical, to that of Bob Geldof would probably just to add to the flavor of this returned Jesus being part of leftist activist circles, betrayed to the NYPD by one of his own just as Jesus was supposed to have been betrayed to the Romans by Judas.

Comment: I have been unable to find ANY relationship between Bob Geldof and the NYPD (other than his daughter's death, that is) so at least that part of it isn't referring to a real incident or person.